# How to remove hover properties from WinJS ListView?

Tags: javascript, html, css, uwp, winjs

I am developing an Windows Universal App using WinJS, but to customize it is quite challenging and I need to follow some design instructions.

The problem happens when I try to remove the hover property from the list element. When my mouse is over the item, the div gets a darker background. I tried to remove it with

```
.win-listview .win-container:hover{
     background-color: transparent;
}
```

and also with

```
.win-selectionbackground {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

But it is not working.

Here is some code to help:

```
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<div class="storyPhotoTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none">
    <div class="story-photo-icons">
        <div style="height: 250px; width: 22px;position:relative; float: left;">
            <img class='xButton smaller' src = '../../images/x-icon.png' />
        </div>
        <div class="pic-area">
            <img src="#" class="story-photo" data-win-bind="src: image" />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<section class="gallery">
    <div class="button lBtn"></div>
    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <div id="storyPhotoGrid"
         class="win-selectionstylefilled"
         data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
         data-win-options="{
            itemDataSource: Photos.StoryGrid.dataSource,
            itemTemplate: select('.storyPhotoTemplate'),
            selectionMode: 'none',
            tapBehavior: 'none',
            layout: { type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout, orientation:'horizontal' }
    }">
    </div>
```

The DOM tree constructed by the framework is not obvious. If anyone need more information, just tell me and I update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover behavior for ListView item is defined in

```
html.win-hoverable .win-selectionstylefilled .win-container:hover .win-itembox,
html.win-hoverable .win-selectionstylefilled.win-container:hover .win-itembox 
{
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

You can find this in `ui-light.css` or `ui-dark.css` files of WinJS lib, depending on which theme you are using.

So if you want to disable the background-color on hover, change the style like below:

```
html.win-hoverable .win-selectionstylefilled .win-container:hover .win-itembox,
html.win-hoverable .win-selectionstylefilled.win-container:hover .win-itembox 
{
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I would like to add that I did it in a different file, so I could preserve the WinJS files the way they are, and overwrite them with a custom css file loaded after them.